# Using tuples in definitions

Tags: isabelle

I want to create a definition which has a tuple as its argument.

```
definition my_def :: "('a × 'a) ⇒ bool" where
  "my_def (a, b) ⟷ a = b"
```

However, this is not accepted. The error message is

```
Bad arguments on lhs: "(a, b)"
The error(s) above occurred in definition:
"my_def (a, b) ≡ a = b"
```

Using `fun` instead of `definition` works but this is not what I want. The following notation also works but is somewhat ugly:

```
definition my_def :: "('a × 'a) ⇒ bool" where
  "my_def t ⟷ fst t = snd t"
```

What is the best way to use tuples as arguments in a `definition`?

Comment: So what is wrong with `fun` here?  `fun` and `definition` are equal in being *derived* definitional mechanisms, while `definition` just happens to be more minimalistic (and allows defining things without arguments).

Comment: `fun` gets automatically extended to its definition.

Comment: OK, that's a certain difference of defaults.  You can say `declare my_def.simps [simp del]` after `fun`, or use `definition` with tuple abstraction as proposed by lsf37.

Comment: Can I _force_ the simplifier to use `my_def.simps` in a certain step again?

Comment: These things are very basic.  You can either use `declare my_def.simps [simp add]` in the theory text, or `by (simp add: my_def.simps)` when you invoke a proof method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `fun` is probably the least painful way to do this, the definition package doesn't recognise patterns on the left hand side.

Another option is to use tuple patterns for lambda expressions:
`my_def ≡ %(a,b). a = b`

Comment: Note that `my_def (a,b) = ...` and `my_def tup = %(a,b). ...` differ when used with the simplifier. The first definition is only expanded if the argument is already splitted. This is sometimes useful and sometimes not ;)

Comment: Just pointing out a possibly-confusing typo in the comment above: `my_def tup = %(a,b). ...` should be replaced with `my_def = %(a,b). ...`.